# sortBy an EL Expression in primefaces

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, datatable, el

Is it possible to use sortBy with an EL expression containing multiple values in Primefaces , if it is how or how can i approach this.

## Problem:

I Need to sory the table by latest date. There are two columns one with created date and another with updated date. if updated exist i need to use it to sort.

I looked at [JSF 2 , Primefaces 4.0. p:dataTable sorting using complex sortBy expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490248/jsf-2-primefaces-4-0-pdatatable-sorting-using-complex-sortby-expression)
and [PrimeFaces dataTable sorting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051814/primefaces-datatable-sorting-not-working) but neither does what i need. second one was just in google search

## Example

```
  <p:column headerText="Last Logged in Date" sortBy="#{login.lastUpdated ne null ? login.lastUpdated : login.createdDate }">
          <h:outputText value="#{login.lastUpdated ne null ? login.lastUpdated : login.createdDate }" >
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" />
         </h:outputText>
   </p:column>
```

Any Advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you force the updated date to be equal to the created date on creation?

Comment: @perissf Structure for entities are already created and should work on old date aswell. Not sure why it is not like that, but will suggest it . Thanks

Comment: Anyway, whatever the entity structure is, you can define the sorting column as such, managing it in the bean, and sort over it...